# How to remove coupon from payment dive after clicking order summary discount code close button in magento2?

Tags: magento2, checkout, discount

I have made custom discount remove button on checkout order summary.
coupon removed successfully but how to refresh payment div discount box code
after removing coupon?

**order summary:**
[image]

**payment div:**

[image: agento]

Comment: What is the js you have used for this implementation?

Comment: app/design/frontend/Vensor/Theme/Magento_SalesRule/web/js/view/summary/discount.js

Comment: Using Cancel-coupon event

Comment: Why not you are just triggering the cancel button instead of cancel event?

Comment: Yes i have implement now that way but just i want to understand the knockout more

Comment: That's good but try if that works what I am suggested.

Comment: Yes it's already working i have implemented too but i want to just check different way